# Problem with deleting row

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hm, First time i see this when i want to delete row:  ( I want to delete respondent.email) i got his:

```
Mysql::Error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`survey_development`.`inquiries`, CONSTRAINT `inquiries_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`respondent_id`) REFERENCES `respondents` (`id`)): DELETE FROM `respondents` WHERE `id` = 4
```

p.s

```
users (table): id, email 
questions (table): id, text 
inquiries: question_id, user_id 
answers: inquiry_id, text
```

Model of users:

```
has_many :inquiries 
has_many :questions, :through => :inquiries 
has_many :answers, :through => :inquiries
```

question model:

```
has_many :inquiries, :dependent => :destroy 
has_many :answers, :through => :inquiries, :dependent => :destroy
```

answer model

```
  belongs_to :inquiry
  belongs_to :question
```

inquiry model

```
  belongs_to  :question
  belongs_to  :users
  has_one    :answer, :dependent => :destroy
```

respondents_controller

```
  # DELETE /respondents/1
  def destroy
    @respondent.destroy
    head :ok
  end
```

respondent_model

```
class Respondent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :inquiries
  has_many :questions, :through => :inquiries
  has_one :answer,   :through => :inquiry
end
```

Comment: So how do we know the way you are deleting a row? Show your code

Comment: ok. next question. how do we know the way you get `@respondent`? Show all code connected with your case, man

Comment: added, i hope you meant this?

Comment: You've listed all models instead exact what you are dealing with. Show `Respondent` model

Comment: LOOl, i''m newbie, sorry, wait  i minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start.

First - it is wrong code:

```
class Respondent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :inquiries
  has_many :questions, :through => :inquiries
  has_one :answer,   :through => :inquiry
end
```

Second, you havent got `respondent_id` in your `inquiries` table and you should define

```
has_many :respondents
```

in your `Inquiry` model.

Third you can't use this

```
has_one :answer,   :through => :inquiry
```

as far as association `inquiry` is not defined.

So you should

- add `respondent_id` to your `inquiries` table
- add `belongs_to :respondent` association to your `Inquiry` model
- delete `has_one :answer, :through => :inquiry` association from `Respondent` model. Or figure out what is it and add some new association to fix it.

**[And read some articles about Rails associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).**

Your problem is not a bad code. Your problem is that you don't understand what you are doing. You should feel Rails and you should love Rails. **God bless you**

Also you haven't got `question_id` in your `answers` table.

Comment: ty! m, still doesn't work , still the same mistake, but some minutes ago i cant edit user, but now i can, but cant delete.

Comment: there is many troubles in your code. (Just in those 20 lines I see). You havent got some foreign keys in your database for assosiations. For example if you said: `answer belongs_to :question` but you didn't add `question_id` reference to your `answers` table

Comment: and you should add `inquiry has_many :respodents` to your Inquiry model and you should add reference key `respondent_id` to its table and so on... Beter read about associations, man